# Can you make IE 9 (or earlier) lay out table elements as if they were regular display:block elements?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-tables

In WebKit, Firefox and Opera, you can set the various table elements to `display: block` to stop them displaying like tables:

- http://jsfiddle.net/bHzsC/

This can be useful on smaller screens (e.g. iPhones) that don’t have room to display tables laid out traditionally.

IE 9, however, still lays out the table cells next to each other horizontally — it doesn’t seem to honour `display: block` on the table elements.

Is there any other code that will stop IE 9 (or earlier) from laying out tables as tables?

Comment: A similar question from long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5091822/405015. It just won't work in IE7, if you were hoping to be able to support it. `box-sizing: border-box` will be helpful if you have to deal with `padding`.

Comment: @thirtydot heh, yes I just found that. I did look first but was searching with _IE9_ and not just IE. You just got an +1 for your answer to the older question :-)

Comment: @andyb: It's funny that you found more of my old relevant answers than I did :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding `float:left;clear:left;` will make IE 9 behave a bit better, but the width of each element will not be correct. If you add `width:100%` to the mix, it seems to behave the same as in Chrome and Firefox.

```
table,
thead,
tfoot,
tbody,
tr,
th,
td {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```

**Edit:** This has been asked before [How can I make "display: block" work on a <td> in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091503/how-can-i-make-display-block-work-on-a-td-in-ie) and partially covered on [How can I get inline-block to render consistently when applied to table cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490416/how-can-i-get-inline-block-to-render-consistently-when-applied-to-table-cells) which quite rightly mention that any padding will cause the `width:100%` to create a horizontal scrollbar. However, this can be avoided with `box-sizing:border-box;`, or by using a suitably lower width or containing element with a fixed width.

Comment: +1 - I hadn't thought of the width. You don't need the `display: block` though. The `float` takes care of that for you!

Comment: Also, where is your profile picture from? I recognise it off a game I used to play when I was little but I cannot remember the name of it. I'm sure it was attack of the something...

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Ah, but the width will cause scrollbar issues if padding is used. Also, profile pic from [Day of the Tentacle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_the_tentacle) :-)

Comment: Oh the joys of accomodating Internet Explorer! Ahhh - yes, that was it. Thanks :) Now I am reminiscing about games like Monkey Island and Escape from the Planet of the Robot Monsters. I think any chance of a productive day has gone out of the window!

Comment: [IE 8 and 9 support `box-sizing`](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/box-sizing) though, so that should sort out any padding issues.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
table,
thead,
tfoot,
tbody,
tr,
th,
td {
    float:left;
    clear: left;
}
```

It might have repercussions on your layout with it using `floats`

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bHzsC/1/**