# HTML table height doesn't limit in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my web application (which includes JSP and Struts2) I'm having a menu which is a html table and the rows of the table are dynamically added.

As it is obvious, when the rows were added then the table height will be increased. But I need to limit this table's height to a certain amount using CSS (max-height).

So, for this scenario I used below css. This worked perfectly in *Firefox* and *Chrome* browsers but didn't work for *Internet Explorer* (verified in IE9 and IE10. IE8 and below exempted).

**CSS class**:

```
.menuLimit {
    display: block !important;
    max-height: 105px !important;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

**HTML tag:**

```
 <li>
    <table class="menuLimit">
       <c:forEach ...
       ...
       ...
```

Is max-height property doesn't support for IE browsers or am I doing any other mistakes here? Please help.

Comment: Did you mention doctype declaration above the html file?

Comment: Why don't you [search CSS support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) yourself?

Comment: you could wrap it in a div and add the max height to that instead

Comment: @Mr_Green: Yes. I mentioned the doc type in various ways but still didn't work.
Doctype1: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Doctype2: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Doctype3: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @Pete OP using `display: block` to the table. so the table will act as a div. So, I think there is no need to wrap a div.

Comment: @zulox just use `<!DOCTYPE html>` and see.

Comment: @Teemu: I know that it is there. But I needed to know whether it can be used with the table tag or whether I'm using it in wrong way in my code. That's the reason I posted in Stackoverflow to get some professional help.

Comment: @Mr_Green I don't think display block on tables works properly in ie9 or earlier - [See section hey what about ie in this](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)

Comment: @Pete yup but there seems to be a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9990553/1577396) to this.

Comment: @Mr_Green, that doesn't fix the max-height problem for me in ie9 and would seem to be a lot hackier than just adding a div around the table?

Comment: @Pete: I wrapped the table with a div and added the whole 'menuLimit' class to the div. And I'm fortunate that this fix worked perfectly. Thank you for your suggestion above. 

But still I'm confused, why this didn't work for <table> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Table will act as a div, but table rows - no(and they have table-row display). I would consider trying to apply those styles to li.

And for the question - max-height is certainly works in IE, though it could be a bit tricky around a table, and especially, situation where you do have table-rows, and do not have table around it.