# display: inline-block does not seem to work in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, zurb-foundation

I want a table with scrollable body with fixed header.

This is my html code. I am using foundation also.

```
<div class="large-10 medium-10 small-12  row">
        <table style = "height: 13% !important;">
            <thead>
                <th style="width:150px">Customer TKN</th>
                <th style="width:150px">Customer Name</th>
                <th style="width:150px">Meter Read Date</th>
                <th style="width:100px">Bill Amount</th>
                <th style="width:100px">No. of Billing Accounts</th>
                <th style="width:100px">No. of Active Accounts</th>
                <th style="width:100px">No. of Processed Accounts</th>
                <th style="width:150px">title</th>
            </thead>
<tbody id="rec_tab_boby">
        <tr>
                    <td id="cust_id" style="width:150px">1234</td>
                    <td style="width:150px">Mark Jack</td>
                    <td style="width:150px">2015-08-20</td>
                    <td style="width:100px">23.55</td>
                    <td style="width:100px">5</td>
                    <td style="width:100px">4</td>
                    <td style="width:100px">4</td>
                    <td class="status-for-popup" style="width:150px">22</td>

                </tbody>
        </table>
```

This id my css

```
#rec_tab_boby{
    height: 80% !important;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 64rem;
}
```

the code works in chrome and in ie 10 and above but it does not work in ie 9.
What can be the problem?

I feel ie 9 is not taking display: inline-block.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle recreating your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you make IE 9 (or earlier) lay out table elements as if they were regular display:block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990173/can-you-make-ie-9-or-earlier-lay-out-table-elements-as-if-they-were-regular-di)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1fe5b7h5/

fiddle for my problem. I need a table with scrollable body. This works in chrome and ie 10 and above

Comment: If you really need the scrollbar in IE9, how about moving height and overflow constraints to the parent div, or wrap the table with its own div.

Comment: but the table should have fixed header also